# Fastest function to find largest perfect squares of a single number?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization, perfect-square

I'm attempting to write an algorithm that will find the largest perfect squares of a given integer, subtracting their values from the total each time, as fast as possible. It's somewhat hard to explain, and I apologize for the somewhat ambiguous title, so I'll give some input/output examples:

---

- **Input**: 23
- **Output**: [16, 4, 1, 1, 1]
- **Explanation**: 25 (5x5) is too large, but 16 (4x4) fits. Add it to the array and subtract 16 from 23 (7). The next largest perfect square that fits is 4 (2x2), so add it to the array and subtract 4 from 7 (3). From here, the largest perfect square is simply 1 (1x1). So add 1 to the array until we've gotten to 0.

---

- **Input**: 13
- **Output**: [9, 4]
- **Explanation**: 9 (3x3) is the largest square, so add it to the array and subtract it from 13 (4). 4 is then also a perfect square, so add it and end there.

---

My solution is as follows (with variable names related to how the question was posed to me):

```
public static int[] solution(int startingSquareYards) {

        ArrayList<Integer> largestSquares = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Cast for use with Math. methods
        double remainingSquareYards = (double) startingSquareYards;

        while (remainingSquareYards > 0) {

            double largestSquareRoot = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(remainingSquareYards));
            
            // Edit - used to be: 
            // double yardsOfMaterialUsed = Math.pow(largestSquareRoot, 2);
            double yardsOfMaterialUsed = largestSquareRoot * largestSquareRoot;

            remainingSquareYards -= yardsOfMaterialUsed;

            largestSquares.add((int) yardsOfMaterialUsed);

        }

        int[] solutionArray = largestSquares.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();

        return solutionArray;
    }
```

I'm asking for opinions on my solution and whether I could optimize it in any way for time/space complexity, simplicity (while maintaining easy readability/understanding), etc. It currently works for all of the tests I've written but I may be missing edge cases or places to improve it - the input startingSquareYards can be between 1 and 1,000,000. Any constructive feedback is appreciated :)

Thanks for looking!

Comment: If your code works then this question belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Tip 1: `pow(x, 2)` is slow. Replace with simple `x*x`

Comment: Tip 2: `sqrt` is slow. If you are using very big `startingSquareYards` then perhaps fill a `ArrayList<int>` with squares and find the closest (but less than) to `remainingSquareYards` (traverse it backwards). Cache the last index in the list, so as to start there in the next iteration.

Comment: @JimGarrison Sorry - this is basically my first ever post. Is there a way to move it now or is your tip for next time?

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks for the tips - both are good ideas that I'll try out.

Comment: Sqrt is not that slow. You’re not going to get much traction looking for a faster way.

Comment: Your problem is implementing back tracking. Consider 32. That’s 16 and 16, but your algorithm will find 25,4,1,1,1. To find *any* solution fast, just return all 1’s. To find the minimum cuts, you need to [back track](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). See also [Dijkstra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Your soln won't work for n*x^2 elements. As suggested by @Bohemian

Comment: Consider this 48 - here there are multiple possibilities to form 48 but what should be your ans? [16,16,16] or [25,26,4,1,1,1]or  [36,9,1,1,1] or [36,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, your exact requirements are not clear. The following code will reproduce the examples of your question. Generally, it will prefer to include the largest square rather than to produce the shortest solution.
E.g. `32` will yield `[25, 4, 1, 1, 1]` rather than `[16, 16]`. This seems to be your intention, as your example `23` is expected to yield `[16, 4, 1, 1, 1]` rather than `[9, 9, 4, 1]`

```java
private static final BitSet SQUARES = new BitSet(1_000_001);
static { for(int i = 0; i <= 1_000; i++) SQUARES.set(i * i); }

public static int[] solution(int startingSquareYards) {
    IntStream.Builder b = IntStream.builder();
    for(int square; startingSquareYards > 0; startingSquareYards -= square) {
        square = SQUARES.previousSetBit(startingSquareYards);
        b.add(square);
    }
    return b.build().toArray();
}
```

It’s designed to handle your specified input numbers between 1 and 1,000,000.

It simply prepares a `BitSet` telling which integer number is a square, which allows quickly finding the largest square number equal or smaller than a value. It’s a linear search, but a search that can process 64 numbers at a time with a cheap integer operation. This avoids any expensive floating point operation. It also has no boxing to `Integer` objects.